# Elasticsearch cardinality sorted wrong

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation, cardinality

When I make a request like this

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/log/travels/_search?pretty" -d '                                                                 
{
    "aggs":{
        "travelers":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"traveler",
                "shard_size":0,
                "size":5,
                "order":{
                    "cities":"desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs":{
                "cities":{
                    "nested":{
                        "path":"cities"
                    },
                    "aggs":{
                        "city_count":{
                            "cardinality":{
                                "field":"cities.name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I get a response that's ordered wrong, like this

```
"aggregations" : {
    "travelers" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 410,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "patrick",
        "doc_count" : 9,
        "cities" : {
          "doc_count" : 10,
          "city_count" : {
            "value" : 3
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "jonathan",
        "doc_count" : 8,
        "cities" : {
          "doc_count" : 10,
          "city_count" : {
            "value" : 4
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "yosef",
        "doc_count" : 8,
        "cities" : {
          "doc_count" : 10,
          "city_count" : {
            "value" : 4
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "mark",
        "doc_count" : 8,
        "cities" : {
          "doc_count" : 9,
          "city_count" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "mike",
        "doc_count" : 7,
        "cities" : {
          "doc_count" : 9,
          "city_count" : {
            "value" : 5
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
```

I wanted it ordered by the number of cities traveled to. If I change cardinality to value_count, it orders correctly, but I can't have it that way because it counts the duplicates.

If any more details help you, feel free to ask for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to sort by a 2-levels deep sub-aggregation, the `order` syntax is slightly different according to [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) (look at the end of the paragraph).

It is also explained more clearly in [this part](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting_based_on_deep_metrics.html) of the ElasticSearch Definitive Guide.

In your case, something like this should do the trick :

```
"order":{ "cities>city_count.value":"desc" }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wish I could up vote this multiple times, saved me a lot of headache, thanks!